# Led Driver Rise time

Tags: laser-driver

I have a simple current controlled op amp based led driver. I pulse the Led with 50khz. Below is a representation of my circuit. (Part numbers are not accurate).

[image: circuit]

I see the 50 kHz signal nicely on the receiver. However the rise time of my signal is 350nsec and I am trying to reduce this to 50nsec or so. I couldn't achieve this. The led data sheet says I should be able to to turn it on in 5nsec or so. The op amp and the transistor is also very fast.

I measure the rise time using my receiver. My receiver is low gain and low capacitance PD with a high slew rate op amp that has a gain band width product of 450mhz.

When I measure the voltage on the limiting resistor (10ohm) I see a very sharp current increase in a few nsec so the driver is pumping current pretty fast.

I cannot figure out what is the problem. Every component is faster than the required rise time by an order of magnitude. Where I may be going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suspect your detector circuit. What is your feedback resistance, and what feedback capacitance are you using? What bias are you using on the photodiode? Getting 50 nsec rise times from a photodiode/transimpedance amplifier is rather tricky, and I'd suspect that you aren't aware of the pitfalls.

It would be nice if, instead of a general description of your setup, you provided a schematic with part numbers both for your photodiode and your op amp.

For fast detection, particularly of relatively high light levels such as you can get at the output of your LED, a more direct approach is a good idea. Consider

[image]

This is from Thorlabs (Thorlabs.com), and can be used to produce GHz response (from the right detectors). It assumes that you can handle a fairly low signal, typically less than 1 volt. You get better response times by decreasing Rload, but less signal. Norm for best response times is a 50 ohm load, which has the added advantage of providing a proper termination of the coax used to connect the photodiode to the load/scope. In your case you can probably get away with a load resistor at the photodiode and a good 10x probe from the load to the scope.

Comment: Detector was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that your op-amp is too slow.

One method that is often used in this sort of problem is to have a constant-current source (or sink) driving the LED, then have another device used as a switch that puts a short across the LED when you want it to be turned OFF.

This gives you very fast fall time and the rise time is dependent on the current source.

Why don't you try that technique and see how you make out?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpiyos.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that you can put the LED in the ground leg if desired and use PNP transistors for the current source.